# IF statements in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have been trying to get a macro to create a new column for me in a spreadsheet that I'm building. It will take either a yes or no from column `K` and, depending on whether it is yes or no, will populate the new column with Pending or Pipeline.

The following is the code I have been using - but this just marks everything as Pipeline:

```
 Dim KR As Long
 KR = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 Range("M1").EntireColumn.Insert
 Range("M1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Status"

If Range("K2").Value = "No" Then
    Range("M2").Value = "Pipeline"
ElseIf Range("K2").Value = "Yes" Then
    Range("M2").Value = "Pending"
End If

Range("M2").Copy Destination:=Range("M3:M" & KR)
```

Where have I been going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is at the end where you copy the **value** from M2.

What you use instead is the if *function* that is set M2 `=if(K2="NO";"Pipeline";"Pending")`, then paste values.

`Range("M2").Value = "=IF(K2=""No"",""Pipeline"",""Pending"")"`

Comment: Hi, 

I had originally tried the following but I get a compile error on the "No": 

`Range("M2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(K2="No","Pipeline","Pending")"`
`Range("M2").Copy Destination:=Range("M3:M" & KR)`

Comment: Oh, you just need to escape the quote inside the quotes using a quote:

`Range("M2").Value = "=IF(K2=""No"",""Pipeline"",""Pending"")"`

Comment: Thank you so much for this - the formula is now recognised but I have run into another problem:- Leaving the cell in the formula as just K2 doesn't link it to K2 on the sheet. 
I had linked up a month-year formula earlier in the macro with the following code - but I have since forgotten where the RC[-1] came from. 
   `Dim MR As Long`
   `MR = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

`Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-1],""mmmm"")"`
`Range("D2").Copy Destination:=Range("D3:D" & MR)`

Comment: I apologise for my lack of understanding - I have never had any formal training with code and am picking it all up as I go

Comment: Excel supports 2 modes of addressing of cells: by name (A1) and relative to current cell (R1C1). That is why I had to change your code from Range("M2").FormulaR1C1  = sth to Range("M2").Value = sth

Comment: I have remembered what the RC[-1] was now. Just choosing the column before the main one. Thanks again for your help. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing a few concepts between VBA and Excel formulas. Your VBA code `If Then Else` statement doesn't translate to an `IF()` formula in Excel. So you are ending up setting only the first cell value according to your `If` statement and then copying this value.

If you want to do it using the Excel formula you can set the M column in VBA like this:

```
Range("M2:M" & KR).Formula = "=IF(K2=""No"", ""Pipeline"", IF(K2=""Yes"", ""Pending"", """"))"
```

If you want to set the values in column M using VBA without using formulas, you need to loop through the cells in VBA, and in the loop use the `If` you were using in your code, like so:

```
For i = 2 To KR
    If Range("K" & i).Value = "No" Then
        Range("M" & i).Value = "Pipeline"
    ElseIf Range("K" & i).Value = "Yes" Then
        Range("M" & i).Value = "Pending"
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The if statement you are using is running in the VBA code you are using so the value that is entered in to cell M2 is simply "Pipeline" or "Pending". Therefore when you copy the cell on the line `Range("M2").Copy Destination:=Range("M3:M" & KR)` this copies the same result to each cell (not the conditional formula).

To correct the simplest way is to replace

```
If Range("K2").Value = "No" Then
    Range("M2").Value = "Pipeline"
ElseIf Range("K2").Value = "Yes" Then
    Range("M2").Value = "Pending"
End If
```

with:

```
Range("M2").Formula = "=IF(K2=""No"",""Pipeline"",""Pending"")"
```

This will mean that when your code copies the cell it will copy the formula down.

However if you wish to avoid using an excel formula you can instead opt to use a loop which means your code would become:

```
Dim KR As Long, x As Long

KR = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("M1").EntireColumn.Insert
Range("M1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Status"

For x = 0 To (KR - 2)

If Range("K2").Offset(x, 0).Value = "No" Then
    Range("M2").Offset(x, 0).Value = "Pipeline"
ElseIf Range("K2").Offset(x, 0).Value = "Yes" Then
    Range("M2").Offset(x, 0).Value = "Pending"
End If

Next x
```